# Remove attribute title from all HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to compleately wipe the title attribute from all elements inside a html doc. From table, p, img, div etc..

Currently I do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").removeAttr("title");
$("img").removeAttr("title");
$("div").removeAttr("title");
// and so on
// and so on
// and so on
});
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Without selecting individual elements?

Comment: But why would you?

Comment: When HTML is loaded on a touch screen device I just want the title to go away.

Comment: $('[title]').removeAttr('title'); You could use the attribute selector so that it just loads elements with the attribute of title instead of every element on your page. https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the attribute selector and select just the elements with the title attribute and not all elements.

```
$("[title]").removeAttr("title");
```

Comment: More efficient than the star selector.

Answer (score 5):

The [all selector](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/), `*`, selector should do the trick

```
$('*').removeAttr('title');
```

Comment: That was fast and awsome, Thank you both!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this using [`All Selector (“*”)`](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/):

```
$("*").removeAttr("title");
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery this would be:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).forEach(elem => elem.removeAttribute('title'));
```

or e.g. to remove the attribute only from specific tags, e.g. `img`:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).forEach(elem => elem.removeAttribute('title'));
```